# Spyder Theme Not Working for Library Commands?

Tags: spyder

Is there any way to have the Spyder theme color commands/arguments/etc. from libraries a different color like you would see in VSCode or PyCharm? For example, when I use pandas, PyCharm and VSCode would color things like DataFrame, assign, to_numpy, etc. a different color like below:

[image]

In Spyder those same things are colored as normal text like this:

[image]

Is there an option I'm missing, or is this not possible in Spyder? Been poking around in the settings for ages with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment (December 2022), sorry.

We'll try to add support for it in Spyder 6.0 or 6.1, to be released next year.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looking forward to the addition, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Yep, we're aware of it and have already some work done in that direction. But we don't have enough resources to finish it right now.